# Application of wavelets in computational electromagnetics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, education, signal-processing

I am a first-year graduate student (electrical eng.); wavelets is one of the courses that I am taking presently. As part of the course, I plan to explore application of wavelets in [computational electromagnetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_electromagnetics) (CEM). The idea behind it is to study a few applications where wavelets are used in CEM, code/simulate them and explain their computational advantages over conventional CEM methods like Finite Element, etc. I have a very nominal knowledge of the numerical techniques used in CEM, and time constraints forbid me from exploring or going into depth.

Can anybody please suggest a few specific application problems of CEM which I can work on? I understand Maxwell's equations quite well. Also, any references/books/online resources of the suggested application would be extremely helpful to proceed.